# inner product vector space Book?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book or lecture course on inner product (euclidean) vector space with problems; please help!

Comment: No book will specialize in that topic. Search the web for (free) linear algebra books and problem sets and choose some whose style matches yours.

Comment: i am looking for diffuclt problems to raise my level

Comment: Just try this book "advanced engineering mathematics. PART B" by Erwin Kreyszig.. Google provides the pdf.  http://www.polo.ufsc.br/fmanager/polo2016/materiais/arquivo38_1.pdf

Comment: Linear Analysis by Bela Bollobas is an ok book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this book "advanced engineering mathematics. PART B" by Erwin Kreyszig. Google

Comment: The appropriate sections of Halmos's *Linear Algebra Problem Book* will do great.

Answer (score 2):

Try *Friedberg's [Linear Algebra](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9332549648)* along with *Fuzhen Zhang's* *[Linear Algebra: Challenging Problems for Students](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801891264)*

Both fulfills your requirement!

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Try Hoffmann Kunze Linear Algebra and Friedberg Insel Spence Linear algebra.Also for visualization you may try Linear Algebra I Hsiung Lin and S Kumaresan.